How to create a thread and pass (this) inside a member function of a managed class without using Lamda in c++
I am using windows winform and i have another ref class detector with Detector.h and Detector.cpp file.
In Detector.cpp file in the member function I want to create a thread which can update the picturebox image.
void updatethread(Detector ^obj, const char* frame) {
    updateDisplay(frame);
}

void Detector::updateDisplay(frame){
//convert frame to bitmap
    Picturebox-> image = bmp;
}

int Detector::Listener(XcAPI& det, const API_SETTINGS& api, const DETECTOR_INFO& info){
//some code
    auto th = std::thread(updatethread, std::cref(this));// my focus is here how can i do it

}

I have tried Lamda but it says we cant use lamda function

Also i want to do this alternatevely but i am getting Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State Details
Error (active) E0289 no instance of constructor "std::thread::thread" matches the argument list
        auto th = std::thread(updatethread, (this->m_picturebox));


Use a System::Threading::Thread instead of a std::thread, when you need to pass a managed object reference.

I have included #include 
this shouldn't be an issue but even after doing this I am getting "no instance of constructor "System::Threading::Thread"  matched the argument list argument type are: (int (Detector det), Detector)
    int Test(Detector det)
{
    det->start()
    return 0;
}

System::Void Form1::button1_Click(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e){
System::Threading::Thread th(Test,m_det);
}

With no integration between C++11 lambda syntax and .NET delegates, it's a bit painful to capture arguments.
With no arguments (other than the target object):
using System::Threading::Thread;
using System::Threading::ThreadStart;

auto th = gcnew Thread(gcnew ThreadStart(this, &Detector::updateDisplay));
th->Run();

Nothing in your code provides a value for the frame parameter, so you'll have to fill in the closure->frame =  line according to your needs.
using System::Threading::Thread;
using System::Threading::ThreadStart;

ref struct FrameClosure
{
    delegate void Callback(const char* frame);
    const char* frame;
    Callback^ target;
    void Invoke() { target(frame); }
};

auto closure = gcnew FrameClosure();
closure->frame = "Test value";
closure->target = gcnew FrameClosure::Callback(this, &Detector::updateDisplay);
auto th = gcnew Thread(gcnew ThreadStart(closure, &FrameClosure::Invoke));
th->Run();

This is what the compiler would have done for you if you had written it in C#:
var th = new Thread((ThreadStart)delegate { updateDisplay("Test value"); });
th.Run();


Can you please explain why you created FrameClosure?
Also Frame is some raw data generated by my system and I can simply pass the frame data to thread but i need to pass the object which has a member function which decode the frame data and show it on Picturebox of winform. My main focus is on how to pass a managed object to a thread. Here I have ref class as form1 and ref class detector.

@Ravi: FrameClosure carries the value of const char* frame, needed by the function running inside the thread, from the creator of the thread.  I assume it's known there, and not through some other mechanism available inside the thread, since if it were known through another mechanism there would be no need for a parameter.  The closure class can carry any amount of data including handles to more managed objects.  If you look at the C++ library before lambdas existed, for example std::bind1st, you will see closure class templates looking a lot like that (but not using .NET)
